# can any one tell A's birthday date in that year?

Tags: logic

Two boys having a conversation.

A : I will turn 20 next year.
B : Impossible! Three days ago you said you're still 17!
A : Yeah, and my birthday was not yesterday.

When is A's birthday date in that year?

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar goes the Western way, then they talk like on January 1 and his birthday was (or is, until he dies :)) on December 30.

Comment: Why can't his birthday be December 31st and they are talking on January 2nd?

Comment: Then, the problem has multiple solutions :)